# how to hide static pages?

Tags: php

i was given 3 static pages e.g

```
proposal.test.com/seo
proposal.test.com/ppc
proposal.test.com/design
```

I checked those directories in the server and there's no dynamic about their indexes, all plain htm file.

the instruction given to me was, hide those url from anyone that doesn't match a random url from database..meaning e.g

if user typed proposal.test.com/seo ,it shouldn't display the page, if the user
typed something like e.g proposal.test.com/seo/a13sdfa   and a13sdfa matched a key from a databased, that's the only time the proposal.test.com/seo page will be displayed

so how am I gonna do this in PHP ? because all 3 directories are made up of pure static pages..

i have done the creating of keys already, i just wanna know how to hide these pages by appending a given random key and checking if it does or don't exists in database.

Comment: Pardon the question, why this? I never heard of this before...

Comment: Is that homework? What have you tried, where did you fail?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: sorry this is not a home work, it's a job related task, i just don't have any idea how to append a random key to a static page url and check it via php :(

Comment: @sasori out of personal curiosity, can I ask you what's the purpose of this system?

Comment: they want the e.g proposal.test.com/seo  to be hidden to public, and only if there is a random key appended to the url that exist in database shall show the page,  like e.g proposal.test.com/seo/asd1323  ..the purpose is, allow the boss/whatever to give urls via email sent manually

Comment: I have added an example of htacess rewrites in my post, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the pages are never considered PHP, you can not block the access using PHP.

You can block access by configuring your web server, for example by using a `.htaccess` file.

If you blocked access the normal way, you *can* use PHP to allow access to the files on certain conditions..

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mod_rewrite` (in case of Apache web-server) and setup a rewriting of `/a13sdfa` into something like `?key=a13sdfa`.  Also you should include some PHP code in all static files in order to check the key validity.

Comment: can you give me a sample of what to place in the htaccess file in order to rewrite e.g /a23sadf into e.g ?key=123sadf , i guess it's the only way to check via $_GET['key'] at each static index pages

Answer (score 1):

How about this: move the static files outside the public folder, so they cannot be accessed directly; redirect all requests to a php file (you can use rewrite engine with apache) which will look in the database for the accessed url/key and return the `file_get_contents` of the corresponding file.

Here's an example of how the .htaccess file could look like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

What this does is the following: if the requested file doesn't exist on the disk (as a file or a directory), it will redirect to `/index.php`. There you should have the logic to render what page you want.
If you don't know in which variable the server will put the slug, just do a `print_r($_SERVER)` from inside index.php to find it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you could solve this problem.

1) (my prefered) Use .htaccess to only display the page if it matches the regex givin in the .htaccess.

2) In PHP (your actual question) 'Get the slug from the URL, query it to the database and if you get a result display it. Otherwise, send a 404 header from php.

Assuming the following: You have an Apache webserver with mod_rewrite enabled (check php info if you arent sure). Your virtual host allows overriding (AllowOveride All).

.htacces

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)  index.php?check=$1 [QSA,L,t]
```

If the file or directory exsists on the server it will display the page. So it would display seo, design etc. Otherwise it redirects to index.php and gives its slug as a parameter named $check. With this variable, query to the database, check te result and redirect to the desired page.

Comment: you mean to say, if am gonna type e.g proposals.test.com/seo  , it would get redirected to index.php?check ?,,but i just tried that and nothing happened, and then I added a fake random key as e.g proposals.test.com/seo/asd23 , i got redirected to a page not found error